# Are animal cells animals themselves?

Tags: cell-biology, taxonomy

If all life can be divided into several kingdoms, and if the cells that make up organisms are the smallest units of life, does that mean that cells are part of those kingdoms as well? E.g. are animal cells classified as animals themselves too?

Comment: This is like asking if your arm is considered an animal. No, (like the cell), it's a sub-organismal *part of* the animal. Recognize that our classification systems (which are arbitrary ways of trying to conceptually organize a continuum of genetic diversity) organize genetic diversity at the *organismal* level. I feel like this is sort of related to [the fallacy of *division*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacy_of_division). I think you'd also benefit by reviewing the criteria to be an [animal](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/boundless-biology/chapter/features-of-the-animal-kingdom/).

Comment: Also, *If* an animal cell was capable of living as a unicellular organism, I would posit that either the cell or the organism as a whole may get reclassified.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

### Eukariotes are more logically defined as unified multicellular groups in science.

You are right that Eukariote cells share many traits with unicellular organisms, like meiosis division, cell walls, inner metabolism, and it is an intelligent view to consider them as related to unicellular organisms in most ways, although your proposition is mostly of comparative and philosophical us, rather than a scientific biological reasoning and description.

Animal *cells share the same chromosomes, which is different from species* of micro-organisms, so that eukariote stem cells can differentiate into the specialized cells. Most species definitions contain a strong reproduction framework which applies to all species whereas Eukariote cells start from zygotes and then communicate with each other with signalling hormones to form a specific superstructure which are used to produce more zygotes, which contrasts with procariote definitions of a species.

Comment: So far as I know (per https://www.genetics.org/content/181/1/3 ) meiosis evolved early in the history of the eukaryotic lineage.  Also, there is no direct connection between multicellularity, hence zygote formation, and the domains of life - so far as I know, eukaryotes simply happened to be the ones that developed it.

Comment: I didn't upvote your answer because i agree with it, just because it showed some effort and contained some accuracies. I said that animals are defined by reproduction type, i.e. multicellular animals reproduce as indivisible groups, typically through zygotes. animals can be a colony which has arms and legs and nerves stemming from the brain to the toes, so they are considered as a unified multicellular groups, because it simplifies useful communication.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is yes, but note this could be subject to debate.  This is a semantic question and someone could decide arbitrarily the other way, but I'm not aware of a formal counterargument, and logic seems to demand it...

Consider [Devil facial tumor disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil_facial_tumour_disease).  I've linked a Wikipedia article there, and Wikipedia usually is very good about providing taxonomy for organisms and it's a shame they didn't do it here, as they are experts in semantics.  [NCBI also does not provide a taxonomy](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/taxonomy/?term=devil+facial+tumor).  But logically, if we were going to provide one, how could we possibly categorize those cells?  They are living, they reproduce, they evolve, they are eukaryotes, and based on their DNA ... they are animals!

A less clear-cut instance leading in this direction can be seen with *[Sacculina carcini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacculina_carcini)*, a parasitic barnacle of crabs.  That does have a multicellular larva, but it is not a very typical mollusc, and it illustrates that it is the cells and descent of an animal, not its form, which determine its status.

Based on these things, I would say an animal cell can *potentially* survive, thrive, and in reproducing itself, become recognized as an organism despite its form.  However, there is a contrary semantics to be considered, notably in the case of the [HeLa cell line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeLa).  In that instance, in part due to the genetic instability of the tumor cells and their dependence on human intervention, a proposal to name them as a species did not gain traction, while I believe some argued with an eye to legal issues that the cells were still essentially part of the *individual* Henrietta Lacks.  However, in nature the definition of an individual can be fluid - in [polyembryony](https://learninglink.oup.com/access/content/barresi-12e-student-resources/barresi-12e-further-development-21-5-parasitoid-wasp-development) one individual can divide into many, and even in humans one individual can become identical twins, so I wouldn't say that an isolated cell *must* remain part of the parent individual.  Meanwhile, cells of different genetic origins [can join into "a" slime mold](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/22574451_Mutual_cohesion_and_cell_sorting-out_among_four_species_of_cellular_slime_moulds), though they usually sort themselves out by species.  In that instance we have a clear precedent of deciding the taxonomy of individual cells of an organism ... but it's not an animal.

Love it or hate it, biology will do whatever it can, without regard for how we choose to think about it.